# Use of block diagrams or graphs in Journals or Conference templates

Tags: packages, graphs, journal-publishing

I have a question regarding the research journals and conference templates given by majority of templates from IEEE, Springer.

I need to add few block diagrams, tree diagram such as spanning tree, graphs from graph theory  in my paper. The template provided for conference or journals are not supporting any additional style files or packages to use like `tikz` or `pstricks` except `graphicx` package.

If I draw pictures, save them in `.jpg` and convert into `.eps` formats and then use in documents in such cases the rendering of images is bad and clarity of diagrams/graphs are lost/not maintained. Also, some conference and journals asks for the source file of `tex` and not only `pdf` file so use of additional packages are discouraged.

What I am supposed to do in such cases?

Comment: Use figures in pdf format (vector format). There is no loss of quality.

Comment: @HarishKumar I could able to insert image in journal template but how to specify the length and position of the image in pdf in journal. I got some bounded box error and also position was somewhere. Am totally newbie with little working knowledge on LaTeX.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}` where `\linewidth` can be a length like `1in`. For position, read this: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020)